# Storing site specific configuration data

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config, configurationmanager

I have been given a job to re-develop a news portal. The website already has couple of thousands of unique visits a day. I am going to develop it using ASP.NET webforms. I am currently in the planning phase and I am thinking to offer the main admin a page where he can change site specific configuration information. Some of these are;

- Web site title "`<title>`"
- site URL
- footer text
- default image directory
- whether to accept comments without authorisation or not

I listed above some settings so that you can understand my scenario better.

What I can't decide is, where to store all this information. Do I store them in a DB (costly?), a custom XML file? or a .config file. e.g. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`

Any pros or cons would make my day!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is to store them on `web.config` on `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration().GetSection()` because this variables are critical and change only ones - in the initialize of the site.

For example the default image directory is stay the same for the rest of the site life, the same and the site URL the same and the other.

Also when you change this settings probably you need also a restart of the web application because for sure you need to re-read them on some static variables.

And because this variables are stay as is, and need them for start the web (then you read the database and the rest) you need to have it in first hand, from the web.config.